# Expand all children rows of one row with a click using TanStack Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js13, tanstackreact-query

I have a TanStack Table example that enables the user to expand the row for one level, and beside every child row there's a button to expand this child for one level and so on. I need to tweek the button of the grandparent row to make it expand all the children rows in this row.

This is the code of the example:

```
import React, { HTMLAttributes, HTMLProps } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";

import "./index.css";

import {
  Column,
  Table,
  ExpandedState,
  useReactTable,
  getCoreRowModel,
  getPaginationRowModel,
  getFilteredRowModel,
  getExpandedRowModel,
  ColumnDef,
  flexRender,
} from "@tanstack/react-table";
import { makeData, Person } from "./makeData";

function App() {
  const rerender = React.useReducer(() => ({}), {})[1];

  const columns = React.useMemo<ColumnDef<Person>[]>(
    () => [
      {
        header: "Name",
        footer: (props) => props.column.id,
        columns: [
          {
            accessorKey: "firstName",
            header: ({ table }) => (
              <>
                <IndeterminateCheckbox
                  {...{
                    checked: table.getIsAllRowsSelected(),
                    indeterminate: table.getIsSomeRowsSelected(),
                    onChange: table.getToggleAllRowsSelectedHandler(),
                  }}
                />{" "}
                <button
                  {...{
                    onClick: table.getToggleAllRowsExpandedHandler(),
                  }}
                >
                  {table.getIsAllRowsExpanded() ? "" : ""}
                </button>{" "}
                First Name
              </>
            ),
            cell: ({ row, getValue }) => (
              <div
                style={{
                  // Since rows are flattened by default,
                  // we can use the row.depth property
                  // and paddingLeft to visually indicate the depth
                  // of the row
                  paddingLeft: `${row.depth * 2}rem`,
                }}
              >
                <>
                  <IndeterminateCheckbox
                    {...{
                      checked: row.getIsSelected(),
                      indeterminate: row.getIsSomeSelected(),
                      onChange: row.getToggleSelectedHandler(),
                    }}
                  />{" "}
                  {row.getCanExpand() ? (
                    <button
                      {...{
                        onClick: row.getToggleExpandedHandler(),
                        style: { cursor: "pointer" },
                      }}
                    >
                      {row.getIsExpanded() ? "" : ""}
                    </button>
                  ) : (
                    ""
                  )}{" "}
                  {getValue()}
                </>
              </div>
            ),
            footer: (props) => props.column.id,
          },
          {
            accessorFn: (row) => row.lastName,
            id: "lastName",
            cell: (info) => info.getValue(),
            header: () => <span>Last Name</span>,
            footer: (props) => props.column.id,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        header: "Info",
        footer: (props) => props.column.id,
        columns: [
          {
            accessorKey: "age",
            header: () => "Age",
            footer: (props) => props.column.id,
          },
          {
            header: "More Info",
            columns: [
              {
                accessorKey: "visits",
                header: () => <span>Visits</span>,
                footer: (props) => props.column.id,
              },
              {
                accessorKey: "status",
                header: "Status",
                footer: (props) => props.column.id,
              },
              {
                accessorKey: "progress",
                header: "Profile Progress",
                footer: (props) => props.column.id,
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
    []
  );

  const [data, setData] = React.useState(() => makeData(100, 5, 3));
  const refreshData = () => setData(() => makeData(100, 5, 3));

  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState<ExpandedState>({});

  const table = useReactTable({
    data,
    columns,
    state: {
      expanded,
    },
    onExpandedChange: setExpanded,
    getSubRows: (row) => row.subRows,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    getPaginationRowModel: getPaginationRowModel(),
    getFilteredRowModel: getFilteredRowModel(),
    getExpandedRowModel: getExpandedRowModel(),
    debugTable: true,
  });

  return (
    <div className="p-2">
      <div className="h-2" />
      <table>
        <thead>
          {table.getHeaderGroups().map((headerGroup) => (
            <tr key={headerGroup.id}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map((header) => {
                return (
                  <th key={header.id} colSpan={header.colSpan}>
                    {header.isPlaceholder ? null : (
                      <div>
                        {flexRender(
                          header.column.columnDef.header,
                          header.getContext()
                        )}
                        {header.column.getCanFilter() ? (
                          <div>
                            <Filter column={header.column} table={table} />
                          </div>
                        ) : null}
                      </div>
                    )}
                  </th>
                );
              })}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {table.getRowModel().rows.map((row) => {
            return (
              <tr key={row.id}>
                {row.getVisibleCells().map((cell) => {
                  return (
                    <td key={cell.id}>
                      {flexRender(
                        cell.column.columnDef.cell,
                        cell.getContext()
                      )}
                    </td>
                  );
                })}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div className="h-2" />
      <div className="flex items-center gap-2">
        <button
          className="border rounded p-1"
          onClick={() => table.setPageIndex(0)}
          disabled={!table.getCanPreviousPage()}
        >
          {"<<"}
        </button>
        <button
          className="border rounded p-1"
          onClick={() => table.previousPage()}
          disabled={!table.getCanPreviousPage()}
        >
          {"<"}
        </button>
        <button
          className="border rounded p-1"
          onClick={() => table.nextPage()}
          disabled={!table.getCanNextPage()}
        >
          {">"}
        </button>
        <button
          className="border rounded p-1"
          onClick={() => table.setPageIndex(table.getPageCount() - 1)}
          disabled={!table.getCanNextPage()}
        >
          {">>"}
        </button>
        <span className="flex items-center gap-1">
          <div>Page</div>
          <strong>
            {table.getState().pagination.pageIndex + 1} of{" "}
            {table.getPageCount()}
          </strong>
        </span>
        <span className="flex items-center gap-1">
          | Go to page:
          <input
            type="number"
            defaultValue={table.getState().pagination.pageIndex + 1}
            onChange={(e) => {
              const page = e.target.value ? Number(e.target.value) - 1 : 0;
              table.setPageIndex(page);
            }}
            className="border p-1 rounded w-16"
          />
        </span>
        <select
          value={table.getState().pagination.pageSize}
          onChange={(e) => {
            table.setPageSize(Number(e.target.value));
          }}
        >
          {[10, 20, 30, 40, 50].map((pageSize) => (
            <option key={pageSize} value={pageSize}>
              Show {pageSize}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>{table.getRowModel().rows.length} Rows</div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => rerender()}>Force Rerender</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => refreshData()}>Refresh Data</button>
      </div>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(expanded, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}

function Filter({
  column,
  table,
}: {
  column: Column<any, any>;
  table: Table<any>;
}) {
  const firstValue = table
    .getPreFilteredRowModel()
    .flatRows[0]?.getValue(column.id);

  const columnFilterValue = column.getFilterValue();

  return typeof firstValue === "number" ? (
    <div className="flex space-x-2">
      <input
        type="number"
        value={(columnFilterValue as [number, number])?.[0] ?? ""}
        onChange={(e) =>
          column.setFilterValue((old: [number, number]) => [
            e.target.value,
            old?.[1],
          ])
        }
        placeholder={`Min`}
        className="w-24 border shadow rounded"
      />
      <input
        type="number"
        value={(columnFilterValue as [number, number])?.[1] ?? ""}
        onChange={(e) =>
          column.setFilterValue((old: [number, number]) => [
            old?.[0],
            e.target.value,
          ])
        }
        placeholder={`Max`}
        className="w-24 border shadow rounded"
      />
    </div>
  ) : (
    <input
      type="text"
      value={(columnFilterValue ?? "") as string}
      onChange={(e) => column.setFilterValue(e.target.value)}
      placeholder={`Search...`}
      className="w-36 border shadow rounded"
    />
  );
}

function IndeterminateCheckbox({
  indeterminate,
  className = "",
  ...rest
}: { indeterminate?: boolean } & HTMLProps<HTMLInputElement>) {
  const ref = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null!);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof indeterminate === "boolean") {
      ref.current.indeterminate = !rest.checked && indeterminate;
    }
  }, [ref, indeterminate]);

  return (
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      ref={ref}
      className={className + " cursor-pointer"}
      {...rest}
    />
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
if (!rootElement) throw new Error("Failed to find the root element");

ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

I tried to solve it using recursion by declaring this funciton:

```
const expandAllChildren = (row) => {
    if (row.getCanExpand()) {      
      console.log(row);
      row.getToggleExpandedHandler();
      for (const childRow of row.subRows) {
        expandAllChildren(childRow);
      }
    }
  };
```

and bind it to onClick event for the button in the row:

```
<button
    {...{
         // onClick: row.getToggleExpandedHandler(),
         onClick: () => expandAllChildren(row),
         style: { cursor: "pointer" },
     }}
>
     {row.getIsExpanded() ? "" : ""}
</button>
```

It loggs the children rows but nothing else happens.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach to create the `expandAllChildren` function is correct, but you have a little bug in the implementation, which is that the `getToggleExpandedHandler` function returns a function that has to be called to expand the row; you only got the function and did not call it.

This is the revised function, which will work:

```
const expandAllChildren = (row: Row<Person>) => {
  if (row.getCanExpand()) {
    // Here you got the handler function then call it to execute the expansion
    row.getToggleExpandedHandler()();
    for (const childRow of row.subRows) {
      expandAllChildren(childRow);
    }
  }
};
```